# Обновление элементов DOM

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, javascript-faq

Как через SetInterval обновить элементы DOM через GET запрос, после добавление новой записи? Например: Есть некий массив `const student = {name: 12, age: 18, adress: 1 str,}`, у которого соответственно свой элемент в DOM-е. После добавление нового студента, в DOM добавляются новые элементы. Но это у одного пользователя. А у другого пользователя, ничего не добавляется, пока он вручную GET запрос не сделает. Как сделать, чтоб хотя бы через каждые 20 секунд у других пользователей тоже обновлялся?

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let tmpStud = students.filter(item => item.id > 2);
  ajax('GET', $ {
      apiUrl
    }
    /newer/$ {
      tmpStud[0].id
    }, {}, {
      onStart: () => {},
      onFinish: () => {},
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        tmpStud = data;
        formEl.reset();
        makePostEl(tmpStud); //функция которая рисует элементы DOM 
      },
      onError: () => {
        'Network Error'
      },
    }, );
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Добавьте небольшой пример. Тогда смогу помочь.

Comment: setInterval(() => {
    let tmpStud = students.filter(item => item.id > 2);
   
    ajax('GET', `${apiUrl}/newer/${tmpStud[0].id}`, {},
        {
            onStart: () => {
            },
            onFinish: () => {
            },
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                tmpStud = data;
                formEl.reset();
                makePostEl(tmpStud); //функция которая рисует элементы DOM
            },
            onError: () => {
                'Network Error'
            },
        },
    );
}, 15000);   @IliaBrykin

Comment: Выглядит нормально, в приведенном коде скорее всего нет ошибок.